# Is there a way to avoid the error statement "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."?

Tags: vb.net, types

I've done some research and the general advice is changing the datatype of the variable holding the expression to Long or Ulong but in either case, I'm still getting the same error. I also tried enclosing the expression with CInt() (or CLong()) to force it to cut out it's decimal portion to reduce the length of the output of the expression but neither is working. It's all pretty confusing. Any help will be deeply appreciated. The code block triggering the error is as follows;

```
 Vsf(i) = CInt((((0.91544 - 0.00166 * Angle(i) - 0.000002 * W - 0.054248 * 
 Superelevation(i) - Sidefrictionfactor) / 0.013939) * Radius(i)) ^ 0.5)

 Vro(i) = CInt((((1.04136 - 0.004528 * Angle(i) - 0.000004 * W - 0.338711 * Superelevation(i) - rolloverthreshold) / 0.014578) * Radius(i)) ^ 0.5)


Vmin(i) = CInt(Math.Min(Vsf(i), Vro(i)))
```

I declared VSf(), Vro() and Vmin() all as integer arrays. I even enclosed the computation expression in a CInt() in hopes that it would convert the result of Vro (which was triggering the arithmetic overflow error) to an integer and hence not have to deal with decimals which would lead to more digits. Yet when I hover over Vro(i), I see a 4 digit integer with decimals. Not sure why that's happening.

Comment: What is the number you are trying to store or what calculation are trying perform? Any numeric type will have a min\max value it can hold or amount decimal precision it can support.

Comment: Really the only way to avoid it might be to start using something like decimal types

Comment: @Hursey, just tried the decimal type. Still triggering errors.

Comment: What would be some example values the variables?  and which line exactly is giving you the overflows?

Comment: Why not use `BIGIntegers`? eg `Dim big1 as new BigInteger(double.MaxValue);`

Comment: @Hursey, so it is the Vro(i) computation during it's third iteration which is triggering the error. And the value of Vro(i) at that error point is -26461.307166963892. At the very least I don't understand why CInt() didn't convert it to an integer

Comment: @JeremyThompson, is BigInteger an implementation in vb.net? 
First of all, it is indicating an error in the declaration statement, secondly from the semi-colon you have at the end of the statement, it looks like a C++ or java statement.

Comment: It's a .Net type - you're right I copied a C# example and left the semi-colon at the end. Google the MSDN information, I think it might be a NuGet package you have to install separately, although it may have been moved into the .Net Framework.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, okay. I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: [BigInteger Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I broke the formula down to try and see where the problem was occurring. Everything buzzed along until the very end. If the value to be raised to .5 is a negative number, the square root does not produce a number. I would perform the steps of the formula without the `^.5` and then check for a negative number.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim Angle = 90.2
    Dim Radius = 100.2
    Dim Superelevation = 37.8
    Dim Sidefrictionfactor = 0.003
    Dim W = 0.00325
    Dim Vsf As Double
    Dim AngleMultiplication = 0.00166 * Angle
    Dim WMultiplication = 0.000002 * W
    Dim SuperelavationMultiplication = 0.054248 * Superelevation
    Dim SubtractResult = 0.91544 - AngleMultiplication - WMultiplication - SuperelavationMultiplication - Sidefrictionfactor
    Dim DivisionResult = SubtractResult / 0.013939
    Dim MultiplyByRadius = DivisionResult * Radius
    Debug.Print(MultiplyByRadius.ToString) 'With my made up values I get a negative number
    Vsf = MultiplyByRadius ^ 0.5 'You cannot get the square root of a negative number
    Debug.Print(Vsf.ToString) 'NaN
    Dim intVsf = CInt(Vsf) 'The Arithematic overflow error occurs here
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow @Mary, that is some real dedication there. I am really appreciative. I actually came to the same conclusion a few days ago and probably should have updated the post to show that but it's definitely good to know, my conclusion has been validated. Now I can find a way to handle that potential error. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a little confused. I actually did accept your answer. I'm relatively new here so I may have this wrong but isn't the green tick indicative of the fact that the questioner has accepted a specific answer? @Mary

Comment: Thank you, yes. I see now it is accepted. Must have missed it before.